# port can't connect, server, localhost

Tags: node.js, express, server, redis, port

So I have a program running a server on my localhost:1234 and when running my program, the server quits to connect on port 1234, but continues to listen on port 3000 like intended.
Relevant Console Log:

```
xmickellx@DESKTOP-JJ707K1:/mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network$ npm run dev

> cypher-network@0.0.0 dev /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> npm run dev-client & npm run start-redis && cross-env ENV='development' nodemon index.js


> cypher-network@0.0.0 start-redis /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> redis-server --daemonize yes


> cypher-network@0.0.0 dev-client /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist

7672:C 01 Mar 23:29:56.314 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
7672:C 01 Mar 23:29:56.315 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7672, just started
7672:C 01 Mar 23:29:56.315 # Configuration loaded

> cypher-network@0.0.0 clean /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> rm -rf .cache client/dist

[nodemon] 1.18.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server running at http://localhost:1234
⠴ Building Well.js...listening at localhost:3000
Message received. Channel: BLO
```

first time it connects like this... But then it crashes and only listens on port 3000.
Further into the long console log:

```
⠸ Building _classof.js...[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
⠼ Packaging...[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
⠦ Building hmr-runtime.js...[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
✨  Built in 16.78s.
listening at localhost:3000
```

I did a basic telnet cmd to check if the port was being hogged by something else and this popped up...

```
C:\Users\Mickell>telnet mickell 1234
'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Mickell>telnet mickell 1234
Connecting To mickell...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1234: Connect failed
```

I am extremely unaware of things when it comes to server sided development, if anybody could help that would be great!

EDIT:

When running redis-cli command, this is where redis is connected to.. 127.0.0.1:6379> maybe this could be the issue?

EDIT:

```
npm run start

> cypher-network@0.0.0 start /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> npm run build-client && node index.js


> cypher-network@0.0.0 build-client /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist


> cypher-network@0.0.0 clean /mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network
> rm -rf .cache client/dist

✨  Built in 32.79s.

client/dist/src.a1dc3d06.js.map     ⚠️  1.19 MB     429ms
client/dist/src.a1dc3d06.js          512.27 KB    25.56s
client/dist/logo.04580eb6.png         50.84 KB    14.24s
client/dist/src.e852c4ed.css.map         957 B       5ms
client/dist/index.html                   454 B     6.61s
client/dist/src.e852c4ed.css             454 B    17.15s
listening at localhost:3000
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to ec2-34-225-229-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:19289 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 34.225.229.4:19289
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network/node_modules/redis/index.js:406:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network/node_modules/redis/index.js:279:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypher-network@0.0.0 start: `npm run build-client && node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypher-network@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xmickellx/.npm/_logs/2020-03-03T05_10_16_605Z-debug.log
xmickellx@DESKTOP-JJ707K1:/mnt/c/users/mickell/desktop/Cypher-Network$
```

Comment: what does "netstat -lt" says?

Comment: hmmm netstat -a reads that port 1234 is being listened on

Comment: can you output it in the description?

Comment: Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1234           DES########:0      LISTENING

Comment: I do not know cmd by heart, can you tell me how to output a description

Comment: you edit your post, paste the output, select all your code and click the brackets to format it as code. But I was looking to see if it would say 127.0.0.1:1234, meaning it would only listen for local connections (which is not the case, I don't know what the problem is) :(

Comment: thank you for your help though, but do you think maybe something else is hogging the port?

Comment: I found out that the redis server is running on 127.0.0.1:6379>

Comment: So you know it's only internal, can you paste the output of netstat -lt so i can post an answer?

Comment: this is the only thing that popped up when executing the command on ubuntu on windows. xmickellx@DESKTOP-JJ707K1:~$ netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

Comment: you should have something listening.. so there's that. Impossible to connect via telnet on port 1234 since there's not server listening

Comment: I don't think my program was executing while I ran that command. There is also another script I wrote and it shows that my entire network will not connect to the redis server. I added it to the last edit on the main post.

Comment: it seems like the program is trying to connect to redis on port 19289, is it possible?

Comment: I found the issue, for those wondering I accidently set my redis_url to an incorrect one by one character.